# Redirect non-www URL to www URL in conjunction with other rules

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Redirecting a visitor who hits `http://example.com` to `http://`**`www`**`.example.com` isn't terribly difficult. But how is it done in conjunction with a `RewriteRule` that directs all page requests through "`index.php`"?

```
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|php|ico|xml)$ /index.php
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make sure that those rule, that cause an external redirect, appear before those, that cause internal rewrites. So simply:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|php|ico|xml)$ /index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

See the answer [for this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88011/make-apache-automatically-strip-off-the-www), just do the opposite.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com/
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I was just writing something similar. I like this way because the re-directing from non-www doesn't interfere with your 'proper' virtual host at all.